# Tyre pressures and Pumps

Tags: road-bike

I have just purchased a new floor bike pump.While checking the tyres on my road bike
the gauge reads for the rear tyre 0.95 bar , 13.5 psi.the reccommended pressure is 130 psi,
maths not being my strong point! Am I just reading it wrong and not moving the decimal point so the actual pressure of the tyre is 9.5 bar and 135 psi.Sorry if this makes me seem a bit thick but I am new to cycling and want to get it right, better safe than sorry and all that.
Thanks.

Comment: For a road bike 13.5 psi would be easy to squeeze with your fingers. If you get on the bike (not recommended) then the rims would be on the ground, and you'd pinch the tube. Roughly speaking, 1 bar is 15 psi. So 6 bar is 90 psi, and 8 bar is 120 psi. I haven't seen tires that *recommend* 9 bar. Are you sure it's recommended, not the maximum? 7 bar is usually quite enough pressure.

Comment: I agree with *better to safe than sorry*. It's dangerous to ride with under-inflated tires, because they deform under load, which robs them of their grip.

Comment: If your tyres are not almost flat then either your pump gauge is faulty or (more likely) you haven't got the pump attached correctly to the valve.

Comment: @scoobydoo yep, but you'd think the OP would notice the load pssh-ing noise every time the pump is operated :-)

Comment: This question has been flagged as *unclear what you're asking*. While it is true that it's unclear at present, I suggest leaving it open for a little while Brian sorts it out. Brian - you'll need to edit your question in response to the comments to make it clear what you're asking of us.

Comment: @andy256 - true. OP, it's worth pointing out that if you have previously just used a handpump without a gauge then 130psi will be a much higher pressure than you have been used to; just keep pumping until you get there, but don't overinflate.

Comment: @scoobydoo - 130 psi would likely be more pressure than the pump can deliver, unless it's specifically designed for high-pressure tires.

Comment: Brian, either you're reading the gauge wrong or (quite likely) you don't have the "chuck" properly attached to the valve.  Many hand pumps chucks are difficult to attach to the valve properly, especially if the tire is entirely deflated to begin with.  You often must press your thumb on the tire behind the valve to force the valve out so the chuck can fit completely onto it.

Comment: A fat bike will use on the order of 7-10 PSI (these have about 3-4 inch tires). A mountain bike which is not a fat bike will use somewhere from 20-40 PSI (these have 26/29/650b x 2-3 inch tires). A road bike will use likely somewhere between 80-120 PSI (on likely 700x23-28 tires). Smaller tires will use larger PSI, and whatever's on the sidewall is just a max rating -- it has nothing to do with how much you actually should inflate those tires.

Comment: @andy256 The whole point of placing a hold on the question is to allow it to be sorted out while preventing bad answers from being posted.

Comment: For other readers: @Michael is a moderator at serverfault.se.

Answer (score 2):

8.5 or 9bar is a usual maximum recommended pressure for road bike tires (23mm width). Depending on your weight and demands on comfort something between 7 and 8.5bar is usually right. Just be aware that road bike tires lose pressure pretty fast so you have to refill them every week or so.

They should feel very hard at 8bar. If you can pinch them it’s way too little (though it’s hard to gauge pressure by hand).